# PhpStorm - Cannot evaluate expression (watches)

Tags: debugging, variables, phpstorm

In PhpStorm I use a debugger. Here I can see current value of variables. Because of a large number of variables, I can add some of these to the watches, to see it more clearly.

But why some variables in "watches" can't be displayed, when there is no problem in normal "variables" window?

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: Collect Xdebug log for such debug session (make it simple as possible -- the less info the easier is to find it) -- only such log may say where the fault is. Ideally is to have simple reproducible code and not full actual app that you cannot share etc. BTW -- what's your IDE and Xdebug version? It may matter as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot evaluate expression" usually comes from XDebug engine itself. In most of the cases it literally means that the expression can't be evaluated at current step.

Comment: Yes, but in left window, it can evaluate an expression, so why it can't do it in right window?